# Which package contains the functionality of gnome to configure thunderbolt through the gnome control center under ArchLinux?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome3, thinkpad

I installed ArchLinux with the gnome desktop (but only the minimal packages) So far I tried gnome-software and gnome-applets while gnome-contorol-center and gnome-settings-deamon are installed. Thunderbolt is working (at leat the thunderbolt dock works with my thinkpad T580 but only when I turn off thunderbolt security in BIOS)

This still does not give me the functionality to see the gnome thunderbolt entry in the gnome control center.

Which package contains the functionality of gnome to configure thunderbolt through the gnome control center ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @don_crissti the feature to configure thunderbolt security levels through the gnome-control-center will only be available in [verion 3.30](https://christian.kellner.me/2018/04/23/the-state-of-thunderbolt-3-in-fedora-28/) (with the exception of fedora who backported this feature for [fedora 28](https://christian.kellner.me/2018/04/23/the-state-of-thunderbolt-3-in-fedora-28/)).

The underlying system deamon boltd and the command line tool are however already [available on the gitlab side of freedesktop.org](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/bolt/bolt).

Update :
[Bolt is now in the Arch Linux community repository.](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/bolt/)

(I can confirm that boltctl works with the lenovo T580 and the thunderbolt3 docking station.)